# Forcing displaying html encoded html as html in the browser

Tags: html, html-encode

I have a huge amount of documentation (approx 900pages) in autogenerated HTLM format. 
The output html often contains HTML tags that are HTML encoded. For example, instead of `<br/>` you see `&lt;br/&gt;`. This error is quite arbitrary, sometimes generated good, sometimes bad.

The generator tool is a third party application (Enterprise Architect), I have some but quite limited influence on the generation process. For example, I am able to change the DocType of the document, I am able to add some javascript. Is there a way to force the browser to interpret `&lt;br/&gt;` as a proper BR tag?

Comment: You could write a console app that would loop through the files and fix the inproper HTML. That'd probably be how I approached it.

Comment: "HTTP encoded" — It's HTML encoded not HTTP encoded.

Comment: @Michael_B: thanx for the tip. I did it, and it works. If you make your comment an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a console app that would loop through the files and fix the improper HTML. That'd probably be how I'd approached it.